# Split a string, tokenize substrings, and convert tokens to numeric vectors

Tags: r, string, token, strsplit

I have a character string:

```
String <- "268.1,271.1,280.9,294.7,285.6,288.6,384.4\n124.8,124.2,116.2,117.7,118.3,122.0,168.3\n18,18,18,18,18,18,18"
```

I would like to split it into three substrings based on `\n`.

I did that using the following code:

```
strsplit(String, "\n")
```

It resulted in three substrings.

1. How can I get three separate subsisting so that I can use each vector for calculations?
2. How can I tokenize the substrings, to create vectors of numeric values?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an approach with base R. `strsplit` is a little tricky in that it returns a list and *also* does not work on a list.

1. As you suggest in your question, use `strsplit` with `split = "\n"` to split into a list of 3 strings.
2. Use `unlist` to change that list into a vector of 3 character strings.
3. Use `strsplit` again with `split = ","` to create a list of 3 character vectors
4. Use `lapply` to convert those character vectors into numeric vectors.

```
lapply(strsplit(unlist(strsplit(String,"\n")),","),as.numeric)
[[1]]
[1] 268.1 271.1 280.9 294.7 285.6 288.6 384.4

[[2]]
[1] 124.8 124.2 116.2 117.7 118.3 122.0 168.3

[[3]]
[1] 18 18 18 18 18 18 18
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use `scan`.  After splitting the 'String' at `\n`, loop over the `list` and `scan` the string to read it as a `vector`

```
lapply(strsplit(String, "\n")[[1]], function(x) 
       scan(text = x, what = numeric(), sep=","))
```

---

Or using `read.table` (as was originally shown)

```
read.table(text = String, sep=",")
```

If there are unequal number of elements, use `fill = TRUE`

```
 read.table(text = String, sep=",", fill = TRUE)
```

**Original answer:**

```
read.table(text = String, sep=",")
#    V1    V2    V3    V4    V5    V6    V7
#1 268.1 271.1 280.9 294.7 285.6 288.6 384.4
#2 124.8 124.2 116.2 117.7 118.3 122.0 168.3
#3  18.0  18.0  18.0  18.0  18.0  18.0  18.0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String<- "268.1,271.1,280.9,294.7,285.6,288.6,384.4\n124.8,124.2,116.2,117.7,118.3,122.0,168.3\n18,18,18,18,18,18,18"
   
string_vector <- unlist(strsplit(String, "\n"))

unlist(lapply(strsplit(string_vector, ','),as.numeric))
```

Output

```
 [1] 268.1 271.1 280.9 294.7 285.6 288.6 384.4 124.8 124.2 116.2 117.7 118.3 122.0 168.3  18.0  18.0  18.0  18.0  18.0  18.0
[21]  18.0
```

Comment: How can I do it without using any libraries?

Comment: Are you trying to get each number separately, or split the numbers pairs with a comma?

Comment: I want to split this string into 3 substrings based on the newline character (`'\n'`), then tokenize the strings and convert the tokens to a create vectors of numeric values

Comment: @Ian Campbell's answer is eloquent and works well. In terms of my answer, I forgot to transform the values into a numeric vector. I will edit for it. You can go with @@Ian Campbell's answer.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `read.table` to read `String` as dataframe with separator as comma (`,`) which will make columns numeric automatically.

```
read.table(text = String, sep = ",")

#     V1    V2    V3    V4    V5    V6    V7
#1 268.1 271.1 280.9 294.7 285.6 288.6 384.4
#2 124.8 124.2 116.2 117.7 118.3 122.0 168.3
#3  18.0  18.0  18.0  18.0  18.0  18.0  18.0
```

We can then use `asplit` to split the data on each row :

```
asplit(read.table(text = String, sep = ","), 1)

#[[1]]
#   V1    V2    V3    V4    V5    V6    V7 
#268.1 271.1 280.9 294.7 285.6 288.6 384.4 

#[[2]]
#   V1    V2    V3    V4    V5    V6    V7 
#124.8 124.2 116.2 117.7 118.3 122.0 168.3 

#[[3]]
#V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 
#18 18 18 18 18 18 18
```